# What does this notation mean $D^2f(tx)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, manifolds

Suppose we have a function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is a $C^3$ function and if $D^2(f)=(\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j})$. What does this notation mean $D^2f(tx)$? Does this mean $ (\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j})$ evaluated at $(tx_1, \cdots, tx_n)$ or does this mean $(\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial tx_i\partial tx_j})$? I vote for the latter. Let me explain how I encountered this question.

Multivariable calculus is always full of surprises to me. Even after some practices, I got tricked over some understandings on manifolds. Last day I was solving a problem which requires this understanding that given $f$ that is mentioned in the beginning if we define $\phi:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ s.t $\phi(t)=f(tx)$ then what is $\phi"(t)$? I was asked to prove that it is nothing but $x^TD^2(f(tx))x$ and some of my friend told me that they have read $\phi"(t)=D^2(f(tx))<x,x>$ and couldn't answer me why is this true? Then I tried to figure it out by myself. I am writing my proof and the reader will be the judge.

If $$\phi(t)=f(tx)=f(tx_1,\cdots,tx_n),$$ then
$$\phi'(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial tx_i}\frac{\partial tx_i}{\partial x_i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i\frac{\partial f(tx_1,\cdots,tx_n)}{\partial tx_i}\right),$$
then
$$\phi"(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d}{dt}\left(x_i\frac{\partial f(tx_1,\cdots,tx_n)}{\partial tx_i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{dx_i}{dt}\frac{\partial f(tx_1,\cdots,tx_n)}{\partial tx_i}+x_i\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial tx_i\partial tx_j}\frac{\partial tx_j}{\partial t}\right)$$
which is same as $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nx_i\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial tx_i\partial tx_j}x_j.$$

Hence, according to my understanding $$D^2(f(tx))=\left(\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial tx_i\partial tx_j}\right).$$ Am I correct? To add more if someone can add some inner-product concept then that would be great e.g I observed that $\phi'(t)=<D(f(tx),x>:=Df(tx).x$ but $\phi"(t)=<x^T, D^2(f(tx)).x>$, shouldn't it be $< D^2(f(tx)).x,x^T>$?

Comment: What is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial tx_i}$ supposed to mean?? 
As long as I have seen, $D^2f(tx)$ means $D^2f$ evaluated at $tx$.

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial tx_i}$ notation means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}$ where $y_i=tx_i$. Evaluated at $tx_i$ means we will calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ and then put the value at $tx_i$ then the value would be $\frac{\partial f(tx_1,\cdots,tx_n)}{\partial x_i}$ not $\frac{\partial f(tx_1,\cdots,tx_n)}{\partial tx_i}$ e.g if we have a function $f=2x$ we evaluate the value at $x=2$ which is $4$.. Am I making sense?

Comment: I don't think I get it. Anyway, the expression $Df(tx)$ means $(Df)(tx)$, and the equality $\phi ''(t)=D^2f(tx) \langle x,x \rangle$ doesn't make sense because the left hand side is a real number and the right hand side is a matrix times a scalar.

Comment: true indeed $D^2f(tx)<x,x>$ doesn't make any sense but does my proof make any sense?

Comment: I still don't get hold of your $\partial t x_i$ notation. Say $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is the function defined by $f(x,y)=xy^3$. What number is $\frac{\partial f(tx,ty)}{\partial ty}$ for you?

Comment: It is $3t^3xy^2$.

Comment: So it is the same as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(tx,ty)$, right?